# TOC out of order in two-column documents

Tags: two-column

I was playing with `\@outputdblcol` and I came up with this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@outputdblcol{%
  \if@firstcolumn
    \global \@firstcolumnfalse
    \global \setbox\@leftcolumn \box\@outputbox
  \else
    \global \@firstcolumntrue
    \setbox\@outputbox \vbox {%
                         \hb@xt@\textwidth {%
                          \hskip\columnwidth
                                                     \hfil
                           {\normalcolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule}%
                           \hfil
                           \hb@xt@\columnwidth {%
                             \box\@outputbox \hss}%
\hskip-\textwidth
                           \hb@xt@\columnwidth {%
                             \box\@leftcolumn \hss}%
                             \hskip\columnwidth \hskip\columnsep
                                             }%
                              }%
    \@combinedblfloats
    \@outputpage
    \begingroup
      \@dblfloatplacement
      \@startdblcolumn
      \@whilesw\if@fcolmade \fi
        {\@outputpage
         \@startdblcolumn}%
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Correct Headings}          
Some useless text that we are provingin Some useless text that we are provingin Some useless text that we are provingin Some useless text that we are provingin
\section{Part}      
Some useless text that we are provingin 
\newpage                         
\section{Wrong Headings}          
Some useless text that we are provingin
\section{Another Part}        
Some useless text that we are provingin 
\section{LAst Part}  
Some useless text that we are provingin
\end{document}
```

But interestingly even though columns are in the right order but TOC is out of order. Why is this happening? and how one should fix it? (of course without changing the definition of `\@outputdblcol` to its original form)?

Using David Carlisle's suggestion, I get exactly the same problem:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\TeXXeTstate=1
\makeatletter
\def\@outputdblcol{%
  \if@firstcolumn
    \global \@firstcolumnfalse
    \global \setbox\@leftcolumn \box\@outputbox
  \else
    \global \@firstcolumntrue
    \setbox\@outputbox \vbox {%
                         \hb@xt@\textwidth {\beginR%
                           \hb@xt@\columnwidth {%
                             \box\@leftcolumn \hss}%
                           \hfil
                           {\normalcolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule}%
                           \hfil
                           \hb@xt@\columnwidth {%
                             \box\@outputbox \hss}%
                                             \endR}%
                              }%
    \@combinedblfloats
    \@outputpage
    \begingroup
      \@dblfloatplacement
      \@startdblcolumn
      \@whilesw\if@fcolmade \fi
        {\@outputpage
         \@startdblcolumn}%
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Correct Headings}          
Some useless text that we are provingin Some useless text that we are provingin Some useless text that we are provingin Some useless text that we are provingin
\section{Part}      
Some useless text that we are provingin 
\newpage                         
\section{Wrong Headings}          
Some useless text that we are provingin
\section{Another Part}        
Some useless text that we are provingin 
\section{LAst Part}  
Some useless text that we are provingin
\end{document}
```

but this one works fine:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\TeXXeTstate=1
\makeatletter
\def\@outputdblcol{%
  \if@firstcolumn
    \global \@firstcolumnfalse
    \global \setbox\@leftcolumn \box\@outputbox
  \else
    \global \@firstcolumntrue
    \setbox\@outputbox \vbox {%
                         \hb@xt@\textwidth {%
                          \hskip\columnwidth
                                                     \hfil
                           {\normalcolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule}%
                           \hfil
                           \hb@xt@\columnwidth {%
                             \box\@leftcolumn \hss}%
                             \hskip-\textwidth
                           \hb@xt@\columnwidth {%
                             \box\@outputbox \hss}%
                                          \hskip\columnwidth\hskip\columnsep   }%
                              }%
    \@combinedblfloats
    \@outputpage
    \begingroup
      \@dblfloatplacement
      \@startdblcolumn
      \@whilesw\if@fcolmade \fi
        {\@outputpage
         \@startdblcolumn}%
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Correct Headings}          
Some useless text that we are provingin Some useless text that we are provingin Some useless text that we are provingin Some useless text that we are provingin
\section{Part}      
Some useless text that we are provingin 
\newpage                         
\section{Wrong Headings}          
Some useless text that we are provingin
\section{Another Part}        
Some useless text that we are provingin 
\section{LAst Part}  
Some useless text that we are provingin
\end{document}
```

I am only interested to how fix TOC in the first two examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\shipout` makes the `\write` in the order that write nodes appear in the vertical list, not in the visual order, so while you have swapped the columns visually with `\hskip-\textwidth` this does not change the write order. Instead of doing that can you not output the columns in natural order but with directives to xetex (or luatex equivalent) to use RTL setting?

```
\hb@xt@\textwidth {\beginR%
    ..
```

---

I think `\beginR` is the *right* way to do this (but it doesn't work) so back to shuffling boxes by hand. This seems to work:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\setlength\columnseprule{1pt}

\makeatletter
\TeXXeTstate=1
\makeatletter
\def\@outputdblcol{%
  \if@firstcolumn
    \global \@firstcolumnfalse
    \global \setbox\@leftcolumn \box\@outputbox
  \else
    \global \@firstcolumntrue
    \setbox\@outputbox \vbox {%
                         \hb@xt@\textwidth {%
                           \kern\textwidth\llap{\hb@xt@\columnwidth {%
                             \box\@leftcolumn \hss}}%
                           \kern-\textwidth
                           \rlap{\hb@xt@\columnwidth {%
                             \box\@outputbox \hss}}%
                           \hfil
                           {\normalcolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule}%
                           \hfil                       
                                             }%
                              }%
    \@combinedblfloats
    \@outputpage
    \begingroup
      \@dblfloatplacement
      \@startdblcolumn
      \@whilesw\if@fcolmade \fi
        {\@outputpage
         \@startdblcolumn}%
    \endgroup
  \fi
}

\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Correct Headings}          
Some useless text that we are provingin Some useless text that we are provingin Some useless text that we are provingin Some useless text that we are provingin
\section{Part}      
Some useless text that we are provingin 
\newpage                         
\section{Wrong Headings}          
Some useless text that we are provingin
\section{Another Part}        
Some useless text that we are provingin 
\section{LAst Part}  
Some useless text that we are provingin
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried that too but it also has the same problem.

Comment: @PersianTeXGroup It shouldn't do (I think) I'll need to try at the weekend:-)

Comment: @PersianTeXGroup Not sure why beginR doesn't work, but I think this is what you intended?

Comment: As you can see in my question, I already have a working solution (third example) and your solution here is on the same line as my third example. As I stated in my question, I am interested to see how one can fix the first two examples; I was looking at your fix2col package and saw how you saved marks, then I was wondering if that kind of approach could be used here too.

Comment: @PersianTeXGroup sorry it was late and I missed that. No `\marks` are sort of accessible with \topmark etc but once a `\write` is in  list you can not access it at all (without luatex) so you have to put the boxes in the shipout in the order of the writes, and move it if that's the wrong visual order.

Comment: The approach where `beginR ... \endR` did not work happens to be the bug of etex. It seems that it gets fixed, see http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/etexdir/etex.ch?r1=29250&r2=29312

Comment: @PersianTeXGroup Oh interesting. Thanks for flagging that here.